# Understanding bitwise condition check for getting all possible sums of combinations in an Array paased

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, bitwise-and

I got an algorithm whose objective is to give all possible sums of all combinations in an array of Integer.

```
private void arraySumPermutation(int value ,int[] arr){
    int N = arr.length;     
    for(int i=0;i<1<<N;i++){
        int sum = 0;                
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){       

            if((i & 1<<j)>0){
                iCount++;
                sum += arr[j];  
                //S.O.P(sum);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I am not able to understand the inner if condition added with bitwise AND.
What is the objective of inner if loop.

```
if((i & 1<<j)>0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's represent cominations of N-element set as N-bit numbers, where `j`th bit is 1 if `j`th item is included in the combintation, and 0 otherwise. This way you can represent all possible combinations as numbers in range [0, 2<sup>N</sup>).

The outer loop iterates over these numbers (`1 << N` == 2<sup>N</sup>).

The inner loop iterates over items of the set and `if` condition checks whether `j`th item is included into the current combination. In other words, it checks if `j`th bit of `i` is 1.

`1<<j` gives you a number where only `j`th bit is 1, `i & (1 << j)` resets all bits of `i` other than that bit, and `>` checks that result is not 0.

Note that this code (with `int`s) only works for N < 31.